# VS 2017 Setup and Deployment Projects : Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.0 missing from Prerequisites list

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I *THINK* this is the right place to ask this question ( since it's not a coding question *per se*, but pertains to the IDE itself ).

I still use Microsoft Setup and Deployment for deploying my projects.

I've done some checking around on the latest iteration of VS 2017 ( community, too broke to afford anything better and it seems fine ). I've gone through the steps of confirming that everything .Net 4.7 is installed via the installer ( 4.7 SDK,  4.7 Targeting Pack, 4.7 Development Tools, I don't think I missed anything ).

I'm seeing something that I know is going to bite me if I just say "Eh, screw it" and proceed forward.

Within the Setup and Deployment Project Launch Conditions I see the following -

[image]

which I've selected.

When I go to the project prerequisites, that option is not present -

[image]

The highest that is available is 4.6.2.

Why is 4.7 not present within this list? 
Is 4.6.2 going to be good enough? Am I still missing something to make 4.7 present within the setup and deployment project prerequisites?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Anyways the prerequisite window has nothing to do with your system but it's likely because you have not updated VS 2017 and/or not clicked "Check Microsoft Update ...". If your target OS is Windows 10 .NET 4.7 is already installed otherwise allow the user to install it (I wouldn't select anything in that screenshot) unnecessary unless you only target 4.7 (which you really shouldn't do unless you have a good reason)

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 ( Professional ).

Will 4.6.2 be sufficient if my application and etc. target to build for .Net 4.7 ( C# 7 )?

Comment: C# 7 is .NET 4.7 only obviously.  But you don't have to include the 4.7 installer, people can download it manually, but again it's included in Windows 10 1703 by default

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but I have zero guarantee my users are using Windows 10, which is why I want this in here so I can have all my bases covered. In general, users are stupid, scared little children, and if they get warnings ( or god forbid have to do anything themselves ), they tend to shy away from using the program.

Comment: So add the installation yourself to your package, the option to do that, is shown right in the screenshot.  However, 4.7 cannot be installed on an earlier build of Windows 10.  The 4.7 installer is only applicable for Windows 8, 8.1 and 7